# How to check if a table contains multiple entries with different values

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a list of products, and a list of websites. Each website can have many products on it, and each product can be on many websites.

I want to find every single product on a particular website that is not on another website, essentially unique to that website.

The only solution I can think of is to iterate over every product, then iterate over each of its websites to check if they have the right URL.

This works, but I feel like there would be a better way to accomplish this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a `belongsToMany` relationship between your products and websites?

Comment: Show us your relationships please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to eager load the products that are unique to the website with the website you could do something like:

```
Website::with(['products' => function ($query) {
    $query->has('websites', 1);
}])->find($id);
```

Otherwise, if you've already loaded you `$website` you could do something like:

```
$uniqueProducts = $website->products()->has('websites', 1)->get();
```

[Eloquent - has() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

[Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eloquent relationship, you can solve your problem like this:

`$posts = App\Product::has('websites', '=', 1)->get();`

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence